# Building dropdown menu from mapped items

Tags: flutter

I would like to build list of items into DropdownMenuItem.
Items are mapped in the following way:

```
  static Future<List<PostListOfDiets>> getPosts() async {

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final token = await prefs.getString('token');

    Response response = await get(Uri.parse('some.url'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
    );

    final List body = json.decode(response.body);
    return body.map((e) => PostListOfDiets.fromJson(e)).toList();

  }
```

...

```
class PostListOfDiets {
  String? nazwa;
  String? opis;
  String? komentarz;
  String? dietetyk;
  int? id;

  PostListOfDiets({this.nazwa, this.opis, this.komentarz, this.dietetyk, this.id});

  PostListOfDiets.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    nazwa = json['nazwa'];
    opis = json['opis'];
    komentarz = json['komentarz'];
    dietetyk = json['dietetyk'];
    id = json['id'];
  }
}
```

For a test purpose drop-down menu was created by this code, but I do not know how to rework it in order to build list of items from items mapped above.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        title: const Text('Some text'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: signUserOut,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<PostListOfDiets>>(
          future: postsFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return buildPosts(snapshot.data!);
            } else {
              return const Text("No data...");
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildPosts(List<PostListOfDiets> posts) {
    return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
            child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                  hint: const Text("Wybierz jadłospis"),
                  items: _products.map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(value: e,child: Text(e),)).toList(), // <- test only
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedVal = val as String;
                    });
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_drop_down_circle,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  dropdownColor: Colors.grey[200],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Nazwa jadłospisu",
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16.0),
                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                      Icons.list_alt,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
          );
```

Could you please advise how can this be done?

---

UPDATE 1

I have updated the code to show full build process.

---

UPDATE 2

I have tried this code... and it looks it does what I needed.
So simple if one knows how to do this... ;)

```
items: posts.map((item) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: item.id.toString(),
                      child: Text(item.nazwa.toString()),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
```

Comment: Convert map to list as . toList() then use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add items to a `DropdownButton` from a REST API in Flutter, you will need to make an HTTP request to the API, parse the response data into a list of dropdown items, and then use that list in your `DropdownButton`.

Here is a step-by-step guide:

1. Add the necessary dependencies
   You'll need the `http` package to make HTTP requests. Add it to your `pubspec.yaml`:

   ```
   dependencies:
     http: ^0.13.3
   ```

Run `flutter pub get` to fetch the packages.

2. Make a network request
   Send an HTTP GET request to your REST API and parse the response data. Assuming the API returns a JSON array of strings that you want to use as your dropdown items, you can use the following code:

   ```
   import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
   import 'dart:convert';

   Future<List<String>> fetchDropdownItems() async {
     final response = await http.get('https://my-api.com/dropdown-items');

     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       List<dynamic> itemsJson = json.decode(response.body);
       return itemsJson.cast<String>();
     } else {
       throw Exception('Failed to load dropdown items');
     }
   }
   ```

This function fetches data from the REST API and returns a `Future<List<String>>`.

3. Populate the `DropdownButton`
   In your widget, you can now fetch the dropdown items and use them in a `DropdownButton`:

   ```
   class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
     @override
     _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
   }

   class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
     String dropdownValue;
     Future<List<String>> dropdownItems;

     @override
     void initState() {
       super.initState();
       dropdownItems = fetchDropdownItems();
     }

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
         future: dropdownItems,
         builder: (context, snapshot) {
           if (snapshot.hasData) {
             return DropdownButton<String>(
               value: dropdownValue,
               onChanged: (String newValue) {
                 setState(() {
                   dropdownValue = newValue;
                 });
               },
               items: snapshot.data.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                 return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                   value: value,
                   child: Text(value),
                 );
               }).toList(),
             );
           } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
             return Text("${snapshot.error}");
           }
           return CircularProgressIndicator();  // Show a loading indicator while waiting for the items
         },
       );
     }
   }
   ```

For Reference Url :

https://flutterfast.com/posts/how-to-add-items-on-dropdown-button-from-rest-api-in-flutter

In this example, `FutureBuilder` is used to perform the fetch operation. When the `Future` completes, the `DropdownButton` is updated with the new items. If an error occurs during the fetch operation, an error message is displayed. If the `Future` has not yet completed, a loading indicator is displayed.

Remember to handle exceptions and error states in your actual app. This code is simplified and does not handle all potential edge cases.

Comment: OK... I understand what you wrote, but the only thing I do not know is how to assign data structure to items map structure. I got the following error message: The argument type 'DropdownMenuItem<String> Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DropdownMenuItem<String> Function(PostListOfDiets)'.

Comment: OK... It looks I have found a solution that works for me (as described in UPDATE 2).